# How to suspend and resume ffmpeg during encoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resume, suspend

I am using FFMPEG to split a video into many 60 second video clips using a camera with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i video="Game Capture HD60 S (Video) (#01)" -preset slow -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -codec:v libx264
-pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 1000k -minrate 500k -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 2000k -vf scale=854:480 -f segment -segment_time 60 -reset_timestamps 1 -flush_packets 1 "C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\test\clips\testfile_%02d.mp4"
```

I would also like to be able to do suspend and resume.
How can I do?
Thank you

Comment: Do you want to pause the encoding of the video or pause the video (freeze frame) during encoding?

Comment: @jao I want to pause the encoding and then pick it up where I paused it

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Linux/OS X you could use this [Stack Exchange result](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17061/is-there-a-way-to-pause-and-resume-ffmpeg-encoding).

> A simple method is to suspend it with ctrl+z. Or you could get the PID
> with pgrep ffmpeg then use kill -s SIGSTOP  to suspend.
>
> Then resume with fg command or kill -s SIGCONT .

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: @guidop21 There are several Windows specific answers in that same link.